# Excel VBA send email Office 365

Tags: office365

We make a macros in Excel to send emails through CDO:

```
Dim CDO_Mail As Object
Dim CDO_Config As Object
Dim SMTP_Config As Variant
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strFrom As String
Dim strTo As String
Dim strCc As String
Dim strBcc As String
Dim strBody As String

Set CDO_Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
On Error GoTo Error_Handling

Set CDO_Config = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
CDO_Config.Load -1

Set SMTP_Config = CDO_Config.Fields

With SMTP_Config
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.office365.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
     .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 10
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "gjhjj@forexapmle.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "654321"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
 .Update
End With

With CDO_Mail
 Set .Configuration = CDO_Config
End With

Dim i As Integer
i = 2
While Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    strSubject = "Z-Reporti"
    strFrom = "gjhjj@forexapmle.com"
    strTo = Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 4)
    strCc = ""
    strBcc = ""
    strBody = "xcvjlxcv  ;lkjladsfgdafg "
           
    CDO_Mail.Subject = strSubject
    CDO_Mail.From = strFrom
    CDO_Mail.To = strTo
    CDO_Mail.TextBody = strBody
    CDO_Mail.CC = strCc
    CDO_Mail.BCC = strBcc
    CDO_Mail.Send
    i = i + 1
```

Wend

Error_Handling:
If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description

An error message with the following text is returned:
The message could not be sent to the SMTP server. The transport error code was 0x80040217. The server response was not available.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using port 587 that requires TLS to work.

Add the following to your configuration:

```
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendtls") = True
```

If that does not work, keep it without the line above and change port from 587 to 25.

[How to set up SMTP AUTH client submission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365#how-to-set-up-smtp-auth-client-submission)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by removing the SMTP Server port.

```
Sub Office365_Email(attachment As String)
Dim objMessage, objConfig, fields
Set objMessage = New CDO.Message
Set objConfig = New CDO.Configuration
Set fields = objConfig.fields
With fields
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.office365.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "[Email]"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "[Password]"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendtls") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Update
End With
Set objMessage.Configuration = objConfig

With objMessage
    .Subject = "[Subject]"
    .From = "[From Email]"
    .To = "[To Email]"
    .HTMLBody = "[Message]"
    .AddAttachment (attachment)
End With
objMessage.Send
End Sub
```